# Sorting in java using value pair

Tags: java, sorting, keyvaluepair

How can I sort this *value/pair* in *Java*:

```
(1,2) (4,2) (2,3)
```

To give me the following?

```
(4,2) (2,3) (1,2)
```

I cannot understand how `compareto()` works. Is there anything equivalent to this code in *Java*?

```
v.push_back(make_pair(1,2));
```

Comment: How're you storing the pairs?

Comment: In your code what is v?

Comment: vector < pair<long long, int> > v;

Comment: This is not Java, its c++. You should change the tag of you question to get more answers

Comment: You should also update the question to include the information about ' v ' commented above.

Comment: @ortis this can absolutely be java. java supports both vectors and pairs, however the java implementation does not use a `push_back` method.

Comment: @Aaron C `push_back` -> not Java, `long long` -> even less Java